# Is there a way to group by month in R if it's a string?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
                date          state             city

1  December 31, 2018           Ohio        Cleveland
2  December 29, 2018           Ohio             Lima
3  December 28, 2018       Missouri    Saint Charles
4  December 24, 2018      Louisiana          Lutcher
5  December 23, 2018       Missouri      Springfield
6  December 22, 2018         Nevada        Las Vegas
7  December 18, 2018       Maryland        Baltimore
8  December 15, 2018        Florida            Miami
9  December 14, 2018       Colorado Colorado Springs
10 December 13, 2018   Pennsylvania     Philadelphia
11 December 11, 2018      Louisiana     Natchitoches
12  December 9, 2018 North Carolina       Laurinburg
13  December 9, 2018      Wisconsin          Madison
14  December 8, 2018     California        Inglewood
15  December 8, 2018       New York  Corona (Queens)
16  December 1, 2018        Florida            Miami
17 November 26, 2018      Tennessee           Powell
18 November 25, 2018        Alabama        Demopolis
19 November 25, 2018          Texas          Houston
20 November 25, 2018     California          Oakland
```

Is there a way to group this data frame(called shootings_2018) by the month,like if it's december, november. I know I have to use the mutate function and then group.

so far I have done this

```
month_type <- shootings_2018 %>%
  mutate(
```

But I'm totally lost and don't know what to do next!! Plz help me! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the month after converting to `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
shootings_2018 %>%
     group_by(Month = month(mdy(date)))
```

---

Or if we prefer to use `base R` `as.Date`

```
shootings_2018$Month <- format(as.Date(shootings_2018$date, '%m %d, %Y'), "%B")
```